# Ideas for approaching pattern matching/distance problem

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to find an algorithm that is approaching the problem of pattern matching.

Basically, I have two strings that have ordered points. Let's say each point is a different city that you pass. I call a segment the link between two cities. Example of a segment is: A-B.
My goal is to find the added segments of String 2 into String 1 (reference).

```
Example:
String 1: A B C D E F G
String 2: H B C J K E F L G M
```

Now, I see that String 2 has the following segments added (i.e. this should be the output):

```
[HB, CJKE, FLG, GM]
```

Here is a photo that explains this idea: https://imgur.com/a/YkuIOvW  I should be getting the highlighted segments in the end.

What is the best way to approach this?

I was thinking about using a distance based algorithm, finding the insertions and deletions.
I also came across this diff match algorithms: https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch

Any other suggestions or how to search this matter are welcome!

Comment: If string 2 might contain some of the same characters in a different order, then you probably want to find the "longest common subsequence".  Those are the magic google words.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- you can't pass through the same node twice (no loop in your paths, for instance this is impossible: string 1 = ABC string 2 = ACABC)
- string 2 can have removed segments only at the begining and end (in your example, A is missing in string 2 at the begining. But then all letters appear in string 2).

The pseudo code is:

```
string_1_next_letter = first letter of string 1
all_added_segments = []
current_added_segment = ""

for each letter in string 2:
  if letter is not string_1_next_letter:
    current_added += letter
  else if current_added_segment is not empty:
    add current_added_segment to all_added_segments 
    current_added_segment = ""
```

Python code:

```
def get_added_segements(string_1, string_2):
    # find added cities
    all_added_segments = []
    current_added_segment = []
    string_1_letter_set = set([letter for letter in string_1])
    for letter in string_2:
        if letter not in string_1_letter_set:
            current_added_segment.append(letter)
        elif len(current_added_segment) > 0:
            added_segment_str = ''.join(current_added_segment)
            all_added_segments.append(added_segment_str)
            current_added_segment = []
    
    if len(current_added_segment) > 0:
        added_segment_str = ''.join(current_added_segment)
        all_added_segments.append(added_segment_str)

    # fill begining and end of each segment
    string_2_letter_to_position = { letter: letter_index for letter_index, letter in enumerate(string_2) }
    completed_segments = []
    for segment in all_added_segments:
        first_letter = segment[0]
        last_letter = segment[-1]
        first_position = string_2_letter_to_position[first_letter]
        last_position = string_2_letter_to_position[last_letter]
        segment_first_letter = string_2[first_position-1] if first_position > 0 else ''
        segment_last_letter = string_2[last_position+1] if last_position < len(string_2)-1 else ''
        completed_segment = f"{segment_first_letter}{segment}{segment_last_letter}"
        completed_segments.append(completed_segment)
            
    return completed_segments

res = get_added_segements(string_1="ABCDEFG", string_2="HBCJKEFLGM")
print(res)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I tried implementing a similar logic using string difference. You can find my code here: https://codefile.io/f/A8C7m6fQWc
I am simply using the ones that are added (have a +), and then I connect them with the adjacent characters.

But, If I swap the the strings, and String 1 becomes String 2, and vice versa, I am not getting the result that I want to. Both with mine and your code. I am expecting to get ['AB','CDE', 'FG']. The FG is not found because G is in both String 1 and 2. Therefore it doesn't have the +. And is a pair that is not included in String 1 (FLG)

Comment: The algorithm should find FG as well. Although in the first string it has FLG, The algorithm needs to find the pair that is not in the first string. Any ideas on solving this? I will try a version with pairs of letters since I am working with segments (a pair of two letters).

Comment: It's not clear what the algorithm is supposed to do. 
For instance: `s1 = A B C D E` and `s2 = A B D E` what should be the output ?